# Using Panda's groupby just to drop repeated items

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this is a basic question, but I am unable to find the correct path here.

Let's suppose a dataframe like this, telling how many fruits each person eats per week:

```
    Name    Fruit    Amount
1   Jack    Lemon    3
2   Mary    Banana   6
3   Sophie  Lemon    1
4   Sophie  Cherry   10
5   Daniel  Banana   2
6   Daniel  Cherry   4
```

Let's suppose now that I just want to create a bar plot with `matplotlib`, to show the total amount of each fruit eaten per week in the whole town. To do that, I must groupby the fruits

In his book, pandas author describes `groupby` as the first part of a `split-apply-combine` operation:
[image]
So, first of all groupby transforms the `DataFrame` into a `DataFrameGroupBy` object. Then, ussing a method such as `sum`, the result is combined into a new `DataFrame` object. Perfect, I can create my fruit plot now.

But the problem I'm facing is what happens when I do not want to `sum`, `diff` or apply any operation at all to each group members. What happens when I just want to use `groupby` to keep a `DataFrame` with only one row per fruit type (of course, for an example as simple as this one, I could just get a list of fruits with `unique`, but that's not the point).

If I do that, the return of `groupby` is a `DataFrameGroupBy` object, and many operations which work with `DataFrame` do not with `DataFrameGroupBy`.

This problem, which I'm sure its pretty simple to avoid, is giving me a lot of headaches. How can I get a `DataFrame` from `groupby` without having to apply any aggregation function? Is there a different workaround without even using `groupby` which I'm missing due to being lost in translation?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What columns and values would your new dataframe have? I guess the index would be made of the groups keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want some row, you can use a combination of [`groupby`-`first()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) + `reset_index` - it will retain the first row per group:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2], 'b': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> df.groupby(df.a).first().reset_index()
    a   b
0   1   1
1   2   3
```

Comment: Why do I need to use reset_index? I'm testing it and in both with and without it, the type returned is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: Oh, the only thing that `reset_index` does here is "reverse" the original effect of the `groupby`. You're correct that you'll get a DataFrame in any case, but without it, the index will be the argument to `groupby`. If you're happy with the results without it, just omit it.

Answer (score 1):

This bit make me think this could be the answer you are looking for:

> Is there a different workaround without even using groupby

If you just want to drop duplicated rows based on `Fruit`, `.drop_duplicates` is the way to go.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Fruit')

     Name   Fruit  Amount
1    Jack   Lemon       3
2    Mary  Banana       6
4  Sophie  Cherry      10
```

You have limited control about which rows are preserved, see the docstring.

This is faster and more readable than `groupby` + `first`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could use [`pivot_table`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2sd6Xs4PLAhXKliwKHW_9AKIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.pivot_table.html&usg=AFQjCNE-vvw4xpcDV9Zt0qJRejgLGPc4nw&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGg) which will return `DataFrame`:

```
In [140]: df.pivot_table(index='Fruit')
Out[140]:
        Amount
Fruit
Banana       4
Cherry       7
Lemon        2

In [141]: type(df.pivot_table(index='Fruit'))
Out[141]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

If you want to keep first element you could define your function and pass it to `aggfunc` argument:

```
In [144]: df.pivot_table(index='Fruit', aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0])
Out[144]:
        Amount    Name
Fruit
Banana       6    Mary
Cherry      10  Sophie
Lemon        3    Jack
```

If you don't want your `Fruit` to be an index you could also use `reset_index`:

```
In [147]: df.pivot_table(index='Fruit', aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0]).reset_index()
Out[147]:
    Fruit  Amount    Name
0  Banana       6    Mary
1  Cherry      10  Sophie
2   Lemon       3    Jack
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I think I will stick to groupby, as using pivot_table for this job seems a bit tricky (at least if I don't want the fruits as index)